# How to show item modified in the past 14 days in personal web part?

Tags: sharepoint, end-user

I am new with SharePoint.  I can see my items with the Relevant Documents web part from Shared Documents library but nothing else.

How can I modify Relevant Documents or add another Web Part to show me every item modified in the past 14 days from the Shared Documents web part.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add or open you existing Shared Documents web part -> Edit the web part -> Click on Edit Current View, refer the below screenshot.

https://i0.wp.com/global-sharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Shared-Documents1.gif?ssl=1&w=612

Then apply the filter like below:

Show items only when the following is true:

```
Show the items when column:

Modified is greater or equal to 
[Today]-14
```

Example screen shot:
https://i2.wp.com/global-sharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Shared_Documents_FilterbyDays.gif?ssl=1&w=612

Output screenshot:

https://i2.wp.com/global-sharepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Shared_Documents_FilterbyDays2.gif?ssl=1&w=612

**Reference URL:**

https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/sharepoint-show-item-modified-in-the-past-14-days-in-list-web-part/